# Find value in the last record and multiply it by a certain percentage until the last record

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1/2006 | 2 |
| 1/1/2007 | 4 |
| 1/1/2008 | Null |
| 1/1/2009 | Null |

I am trying to find either a query or VBA code for Microsoft Access:
If the value is null, use the last available value (i.e.) 4 in our case and grow it by certain percentage like 2.5% etc. So null will be replaced by 4*1.025=5 and so on until the last record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the table as a *recordset* using VBA and loop the records while storing the value of *Value*.

When the value of Value reaches a *Null*, update the record's Value using your formula and the stored value from the previous record, store that value and continue with the next record, update this, and so on until no more records.

You may try to modify your code like this (air code):

```vb
Public Function UpdateValue()

    Const factor As Currency = 1.025

    Dim forecast As Currency

    With CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select value from macroforecastbudget order by [Date]")
   
        If Not .EOF Then
            .MoveFirst
            Do Until .EOF
                If Not IsNull(!Value) Then
                    forecast = !Value
                Else
                    forecast = forecast * factor
                    .Edit
                    !Value = forecast
                    .Update
                End If
                .MoveNext
            Loop
        End If
        .Close

    End With

End Function
```

Comment: no need for recursive here. see my answer below.

Comment: Sorry, @DannySlor, T-SQL is not Access SQL.

Comment: Hi Gustav, Can you please share the VBA code to refer to previous record?

Comment: Yes, see extended answer, please.

Comment: Hi Gustav, I tried and modified it a bit but what it does is that it makes all the values = 0. What i wanted was the initial values to the same and where it's blank, just use the last value and grow it by 1.025

Comment: Yes, the recordset should not include _Null_ values only. See edited answer, please.

Comment: So, Musab, where did my accepted mark for a proven solution go?

Comment: Thanks Gustav. I will try it and see . Sorry I am new to StackOverflow. I have marked your solution as accepted again.

Comment: Thanks! In your now deleted answer, you forgot to remove the _where_ clause.